# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset

Tags: mysql

После перемещения на другой хостинг ошибки. Помогите пожалуйста исправить.

```
 PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'product_id' in /catalog/model/account/report.php on line 146
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'start' in catalog/model/account/report.php on line 128

PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'limit' in /catalog/model/account/report.php on line 132
```

Вот содержание файла:

```
<?php
class ModelAccountReport extends Model {
    public function getTotalOrd($product_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product  WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

        return ($query->row['total']);
    }

    public function getTotalMess($product_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "messages_shop  WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND email <> ''");

        return ($query->row['total']);
    }

    public function getId($order_product_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT order_id FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` WHERE order_product_id = '" . (int)$order_product_id . "'");
        if ($query->num_rows) {
            return $query->row['order_id'];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //***********************************************************************************************//

    public function getOrder($order_id) {
        $order_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'  AND order_status_id > '0'");

        if ($order_query->num_rows) {
            $country_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "country` WHERE country_id = '" . (int)$order_query->row['payment_country_id'] . "'");

            if ($country_query->num_rows) {
                $payment_iso_code_2 = $country_query->row['iso_code_2'];
                $payment_iso_code_3 = $country_query->row['iso_code_3'];
            } else {
                $payment_iso_code_2 = '';
                $payment_iso_code_3 = '';
            }

            $zone_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "zone` WHERE zone_id = '" . (int)$order_query->row['payment_zone_id'] . "'");

            if ($zone_query->num_rows) {
                $payment_zone_code = $zone_query->row['code'];
            } else {
                $payment_zone_code = '';
            }

            $country_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "country` WHERE country_id = '" . (int)$order_query->row['shipping_country_id'] . "'");

            if ($country_query->num_rows) {
                $shipping_iso_code_2 = $country_query->row['iso_code_2'];
                $shipping_iso_code_3 = $country_query->row['iso_code_3'];
            } else {
                $shipping_iso_code_2 = '';
                $shipping_iso_code_3 = '';
            }

            $zone_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "zone` WHERE zone_id = '" . (int)$order_query->row['shipping_zone_id'] . "'");

            if ($zone_query->num_rows) {
                $shipping_zone_code = $zone_query->row['code'];
            } else {
                $shipping_zone_code = '';
            }

            return array(
                'order_id'                => $order_query->row['order_id'],
                'invoice_no'              => $order_query->row['invoice_no'],
                'invoice_prefix'          => $order_query->row['invoice_prefix'],
                'store_id'                => $order_query->row['store_id'],
                'store_name'              => $order_query->row['store_name'],
                'store_url'               => $order_query->row['store_url'],
                'customer_id'             => $order_query->row['customer_id'],
                'firstname'               => $order_query->row['firstname'],
                'lastname'                => $order_query->row['lastname'],
                'telephone'               => $order_query->row['telephone'],
                'fax'                     => $order_query->row['fax'],
                'email'                   => $order_query->row['email'],
                'payment_firstname'       => $order_query->row['payment_firstname'],
                'payment_lastname'        => $order_query->row['payment_lastname'],
                'payment_company'         => $order_query->row['payment_company'],
                'payment_address_1'       => $order_query->row['payment_address_1'],
                'payment_address_2'       => $order_query->row['payment_address_2'],
                'payment_postcode'        => $order_query->row['payment_postcode'],
                'payment_city'            => $order_query->row['payment_city'],
                'payment_zone_id'         => $order_query->row['payment_zone_id'],
                'payment_zone'            => $order_query->row['payment_zone'],
                'payment_zone_code'       => $payment_zone_code,
                'payment_country_id'      => $order_query->row['payment_country_id'],
                'payment_country'         => $order_query->row['payment_country'],
                'payment_iso_code_2'      => $payment_iso_code_2,
                'payment_iso_code_3'      => $payment_iso_code_3,
                'payment_address_format'  => $order_query->row['payment_address_format'],
                'payment_method'          => $order_query->row['payment_method'],
                'shipping_firstname'      => $order_query->row['shipping_firstname'],
                'shipping_lastname'       => $order_query->row['shipping_lastname'],
                'shipping_company'        => $order_query->row['shipping_company'],
                'shipping_address_1'      => $order_query->row['shipping_address_1'],
                'shipping_address_2'      => $order_query->row['shipping_address_2'],
                'shipping_postcode'       => $order_query->row['shipping_postcode'],
                'shipping_city'           => $order_query->row['shipping_city'],
                'shipping_zone_id'        => $order_query->row['shipping_zone_id'],
                'shipping_zone'           => $order_query->row['shipping_zone'],
                'shipping_zone_code'      => $shipping_zone_code,
                'shipping_country_id'     => $order_query->row['shipping_country_id'],
                'shipping_country'        => $order_query->row['shipping_country'],
                'shipping_iso_code_2'     => $shipping_iso_code_2,
                'shipping_iso_code_3'     => $shipping_iso_code_3,
                'shipping_address_format' => $order_query->row['shipping_address_format'],
                'shipping_method'         => $order_query->row['shipping_method'],
                'comment'                 => $order_query->row['comment'],
                'total'                   => $order_query->row['total'],
                'order_status_id'         => $order_query->row['order_status_id'],
                'language_id'             => $order_query->row['language_id'],
                'currency_id'             => $order_query->row['currency_id'],
                'currency_code'           => $order_query->row['currency_code'],
                'currency_value'          => $order_query->row['currency_value'],
                'date_modified'           => $order_query->row['date_modified'],
                'date_added'              => $order_query->row['date_added'],
                'ip'                      => $order_query->row['ip']
            );
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getOrders($data = array()) {
        if ($data['start'] < 0) {
            $data['start'] = 0;
        }

        if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
            $data['limit'] = 100;
        }

      //$query = $this->db->query("SELECT o.order_id, o.firstname, o.lastname, os.name as status, o.date_added, o.total, o.currency_code, o.currency_value FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os ON (o.order_status_id = os.order_status_id) WHERE o.shop_id = '" . (int)$this->shop->Manufacturer() . "' AND o.order_status_id > '0' AND o.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY o.order_id DESC LIMIT " . (int)$start . "," . (int)$limit);
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order o ON (op.order_id = o.order_id) WHERE op.product_id = '" . (int)$data['product_id'] . "' AND o.order_status_id <> 0 ORDER BY op.order_product_id DESC LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit']);
        return $query->rows;
    }

    public function getTotalOrders($data = array()) {
      //    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o WHERE shop_id = '" . (int)$this->shop->Manufacturer() . "' AND o.order_status_id > '0' AND o.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");

      //    return $query->row['total'];
      $cat = array();
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT op.order_id FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order o ON (op.order_id = o.order_id) WHERE op.product_id = '" . (int)$data['product_id'] . "' AND o.order_status_id <> 0");

      foreach ($query->rows as $row) {
                $cat[] = $row['order_id'];
             }
     return  count(array_unique($cat));
    }


    public function getOrderProduct($order_id, $order_product_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' AND order_product_id = '" . (int)$order_product_id . "'");

        return $query->row;
    }

    public function getOrderProducts($order_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");

        return $query->rows;
    }

    public function getOrderProduct2($order_product_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product WHERE order_product_id = '" . (int)$order_product_id . "'");
        if ($query->num_rows) {
            return array(
                'name'             => $query->row['name'],
                'op'       => $query->row['op']
                    );
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getOrderOptions($order_id, $order_product_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_option WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' AND order_product_id = '" . (int)$order_product_id . "'");

        return $query->rows;
    }

    public function getOrderVouchers($order_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_voucher` WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");

        return $query->rows;
    }

    public function getOrderOrders($order_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_new` WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");

        return $query->rows;
    }

    public function getOrderTotals($order_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_total WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' ORDER BY sort_order");

        return $query->rows;
    }

    public function getOrderHistories($order_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT date_added, os.name AS status, oh.comment, oh.notify FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_history oh LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os ON oh.order_status_id = os.order_status_id WHERE oh.order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY oh.date_added");

        return $query->rows;
    }


    public function getTotalOrderProductsByOrderId($order_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");

        return $query->row['total'];
    }

    public function getTotalOrderVouchersByOrderId($order_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_voucher` WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");

        return $query->row['total'];
    }
}
```

Comment: возможно в запросе ошибка?  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT op.order_id FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order o ON (op.order_id = o.order_id) WHERE op.product_id = '" . (int)$data['product_id'] . "' AND o.order_status_id <> 0");

Comment: Ну он же вам пишет, что не может найти ключи `product_id`, `start`, `limit` в массиве. Ищите эти ключи и исправляйте

Comment: всё понял как поправить

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getOrders($product_id, $start = 0, $limit = 20) {
        if ($start < 0) {
            $start = 0;
        }

        if ($limit < 1) {
            $limit = 1;
        }
```

Исправил вот так и всё заработало.